# error No '*' candidate produce the expected contextual result type 'Array<Double>'

Tags: swift

```
class NN {
    var ni = 2
    var ai = Array<Double>()


    init(ni:NSInteger)
    {
        self.ni = ni

        self.ai = [1.0]*&self.ni //error

    }
}
```

I am having trouble multiplying an inout variable with a double. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The error is stated in the title. I am receiving error for that following line of code.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `*&self.ni`? What is the `&` for? Why do you think you can multiply an array of `Double` and a `Int`?

Comment: I apologize for my lack of experience as I am still learning  Swift 3. I receive the following error for multiplying self.ai = [1.0] * &Double(self.ni). This code was from an outdated Github project.

Comment: I know which line is causing the error. I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do with that line of code. Obviously it is incorrect. Explain what it is that line is supposed to do so someone can help you fix it.

Comment: This code was from a neural network Github project (https://github.com/vlall/Swift-Brain/blob/master/source/NeuralNetwork.swift). I am attempting to decipher it.

Comment: According to the project, I'm trying to init the array as [1.0]*self.ni. However, the code is from Swift 2.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/vlall/Swift-Brain/blob/master/source/math/Matrix.swift

That class defines the operator `*&` which lets you multiple an array of `Double` with an `Int`. Once you add that file to your project then the line of code giving you the problem in your question will start working.

Comment: Hello. Sorry to be bothering you. But what would the infix operator be for *& for Swift 3?